# Azure Devops Pipeline with .NET Framework version 4.8 - code coverage is always shown as 0.0% on the Sonarqube

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-devops, sonarqube, code-coverage

Executing the pipeline from Azure Devops Pipeline with .NET Framework 4.8.

- The code coverage is enabled
- The task "Visual Studio test assemblies" gets "Unsupported Target Framework:.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259"
- [Azure devops job and tasks added Argument "a"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1oDi.png)
- SonarQube code coverage shows 0.0% [code coverage result at sonarqube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Zzh.png)

Tried the Sonarqube documentation on Azure Devops .NET Framework
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/dotnet-test-coverage/

Verified the .NET versions installed "dotnet sdk check"
[dotnet versions on Azure devops server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTzwa.png)